# Computer won't boot to system rescue CD, goes to GRUB bootloader instead

Tags: boot, grub, secure-erase, dban

I'm trying to wipe a hard disk and am using System Rescue CD so I can launch DBAN from it. When the computer is powered on I press F12 to get to the boot menu but it doesn't come up and goes into the GRUB manager instead to boot Red Hat. I tried pressing F2 for "setup" but nothing happened either. How can I use DBAN to wipe the disk? The computer is a Dell Dimension 3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a wired USB keyboard (or a PS/2 keyboard if available) rather than a wireless one to access pre-OS environments.

However, according to [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/17751635/17874621.aspx#17875684) regarding the **Dell Dimension 3000** you simply need to plug the keyboard into another USB port.

You could also just pull the drive and put it into another machine for the purposes of wiping it.

Comment: I am using a wired USB keyboard. Why do you suspect the problem is with the computer and not the hard drive?

Comment: The BIOS decides which *hardware devices* are selected to boot not the harddrive. The harddrive may contain a bootloader that boots a specific partition on the harddrive (with "help" from the BIOS). The F2, F12, etc. keys are shortcuts to BIOS menus which are part of the firmware on the motherboard. Did you read the thread I linked about your computer model?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [THIS](http://phanvinhthinh.blogspot.com/2010/08/boot-from-usb-flash-without-bios.html) webpage can be of help. It give instructions on how to install a certain "smart" boot selector, known as Plop, as a GRUB2 Option. That way, when GRUB2 appears, you can select the Plop option, and force your computer to boot from USB.